# Can you obtain the ABI of a smart contract using the contract address and contract code?

Tags: abi

I have an ABI I'm trying to use to execute a withdraw of Ethereum from a smart contract via MyEtherWallet, but I'm receiving an error of "Please enter a valid ABI."

I'm concerned the ABI I have is not correct so is there a way to generate the ABI myself using the contract address and contract code? Needless to say, I am new to smart contracts and not a programmer.

Answer (score 2):

You need the source code to generate the abi. Having only the contract address and the evm bytecode is not enough.

You can try using reverse engineering with the evm code but it is way too hard and can be impossible if the contracts was written in a language that don't follow solidity abi.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I was fortunately able to obtain the correct abi.

Answer (score 1):

You can visit remix and get there abi of your contract's source code and then visit [online abi encoder from HashEx](https://abi.hashex.org) to parse this abi and after you can choose and enter parameters you want to use and get your encoded abi, which you can use after. Also there are FAQ about how to use it.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I was fortunately able to obtain the correct abi.