# What if I don't verify a contract?

Tags: web3js, contract-verification

I have a question, what if I have a simple contract that has a  public function "give something to this adress" and that will be called from a website

I will put it on-chain but will not verify it nor publish the abi or source code...

So, is there a way someone can decode the bytecode generated for my contract? Is there any way they can generate their own abi? And the last question: Can someone access the abi that I use on my webpage?

Comment: Nobody knows? I think the problem will be when they actually come to the webpage and download it since there will be the ABI. But I can be wrong so please I'll apreciate if you help me.

Comment: Thx for edit  @chenmunka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solidity code is compiled into EVM bytecode. All compiled code can, at least in theory, be reverse-engineered.

Reverse-engineering any compiled code gives us the basic functionality in a very unreadable format (it's optimized, minimized and whatnot). Some more info can be found here: [How can you decompile a smart contract?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/188/how-can-you-decompile-a-smart-contract)

Having spent a minute googling the issue, it looks like you can't get the ABI from just the bytecode: [Can you obtain the ABI of a smart contract using the contract address and contract code?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/43606/can-you-obtain-the-abi-of-a-smart-contract-using-the-contract-address-and-contra) and [How do you get a json file (ABI) from a known contract address?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3149/how-do-you-get-a-json-file-abi-from-a-known-contract-address)

Anyway, as a rule of thumb, don't assume ANY information you put into Ethereum blockchain to remain secret (unless it's encrypted in client-side and not decryptable in the blockchain).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll be careful. Do you know if someone can get the ABI if he downloads my website? Assuming I use Web3.is i.e I put the ABI on the website?

Comment: Well if the ABI is on the website publicly then they can get it. But you cuold hide it somewhere within your backend I guess.

Comment: Yeah I'll try, however, thanks man, I appreciate it!